# Stochastic Gradient Descent with integer arithmetics

Tags: optimization, machine-learning

Most implementations of stochastic gradient descent (SGD) rely on floating points.
Is there implementations using infinite or finite precision integer arithmetics ?

Comment: Is this question about the theory of stochastic gradient descent or about finding a suitable software package?

Comment: The former. I'm not looking for a software library for SGD but rather if there is a paper describing a variant of the algorithm using integer arithmetics.

Comment: why would you want to do that? performance? limited hardware?

Comment: I don't really understand the question.  Can't we just represent the floating points using integers?

Comment: eh - representing floating point via ints causes all kinds of numerical problems. The "correct" approach is to use adaptively growing (or even infinite) precision as is done in many geometric questions.

Comment: I see. This reminds me why I never went into numerical analysis...

Comment: I am not sure I understand the point of your question. Why not just change the algorithm to use other representations? (like nested intervals?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see eg [Neural network training with constrained integer weights](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=785521)
Plagianakos, V.P.;   Vrahatis, M.N.;

[An Integer Recurrent Artificial Neural Network
for Classifying Feature Vectors](http://www.dice.ucl.ac.be/Proceedings/esann/esannpdf/es1999-18.pdf) 
Roelof K Brouwer PEng, Ph

the general idea in various implementations is to represent/approximate real numbers $x \in[0..1]$ as integers in the form $x \cdot 10^m$ where $m$ is some integer exponent.